# MVC two different connection strings in data context

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dbcontext

I currently have 2 dbcontext classes set up that use different connection strings. Whenever I try to select from the "Cedulados" table it winds up using the "DefaultConnection" string for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
       : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SEG_CEmpleados> Empleados { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SEG_CEmpNuevo> EmpleadosNuevos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SEG_Estados> Estados { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SEG_Tarjetas> Tarjetas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SEG_Visitantes> Visitantes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SEG_Tipos> Tipos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SEG_TiposDoc> TiposDoc { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SEG_Departamentos> Departamentos { get; set; }
    internal void Refresh(RefreshMode clientWins, object articles)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}

public class CeduladosContext : DbContext
{
    public CeduladosContext()
       : base("Cedulados")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Cedulados20110712> Cedulados { get; set; } 

    internal void Refresh(RefreshMode clientWins, object articles)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public JsonResult PerCedula(string id)


{
    string mun = id.Substring(0, 3);
    string seq = id.Substring(3, 7);
    string ver = id.Substring(10, 1);

    var context = new CeduladosContext();

    var ced = context.Cedulados.FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(ced, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (note "name=" in the constructor parameter):

```
public DataContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
public CeduladosContext() : base("name=Cedulados")
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I searched MSDN for the DbContext Constructor and it says it takes the database name or connection string as a parameter. In your question, you said you are selecting from the table Cedulados, which you are also passing to your DbContext. It seems you should pass the database name instead of the table name. Or is your database also named "Cedulados?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx

Here is another resource demonstrating similar code with explanations to what you posted.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx